# AzCopy: How to know if the copy was success or not

Tags: powershell, azcopy

I have a script in Ubuntu that copy only one file each hour to the Storage Account. I am using `azcopy filename.tar https://<storage>.blob.core.windows.net/<container>`.

This script is working but I'd like to check if the copy was success or not, for example:

```
validcopy = azcopy copy filename.tar https://<storage>.blob.core.windows.net/<container>
if(validcopy){
    echo "Success"
} else {
    echo "Failure"
}
```

Also, I tried using Power Shell in linux (pwsh), but unsuccess.

Please, can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a alternative solution for this issue.
I used exit code in bash shell. Every Linux or Unix command executed by the shell script or user has an exit status. Exit status is an integer number. 0 exit status means the command was successful without any errors. A non-zero (1-255 values) exit status means command was a failure.

A particular shell variable called `$?` to get the exit status of the previously executed command

It was like this:

```
azcopy copy filename.tar https://<storage>.blob.core.windows.net/<container>
if [[ $? -gt 0 ]]
then
    echo "Failure"
else 
    echo "Success"
fi
```