# How can I confirm if azcopy synced successfully a dir?

Tags: bash, azure, synchronization, azure-blob-storage, azcopy

I have a group of files and directories stored in a container in a storage account in Azure. I am using the `sync` operation of `azcopy` to bring only the files and directories that I am missing into a local directory. When executing the command I use the `--delete-destination true` flag and the `--recursive` flag. The command is executed as part of a bash script.

How can I check if the sync process was successful? I've noticed that `azcopy` doesn't necessarily return a zero exit code even though the sync was successful. Other users have mentioned that [checking the exit code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67417596) with the `copy` operation of `azcopy` has worked for them. However, it seems that the story is different with the `sync` operation.

Currently what I do is delete in my local directory a file that I know will always exist in all Azure containers that I have to sync with `azcopy sync`. After deleting the file, I run `azcopy sync` and when finished I check if the file I had deleted was restored... This is clearly not the ideal solution.

I am considering checking the logs from each one of the jobs that `azcopy` creates, or exploring the `--mirror-mode` flag or even figuring out if the details provided by `--dry-run` can help me review if everything went according to plan.

However, all these options seem to be too much for something that should be way much simpler. So, most likely, there is something here that I am missing...

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

I tried the same steps in my environment first I copied from storage account to local environment using Azcopy command.

**Command:**

```
azcopy copy `"https://venkat123.blob.core.windows.net/container1/<SAS-token>" "C:\Users\xxxx" --recursive`
```

The above command has copied two files to local environment.

[image]

> delete in my local directory a file that I know will always exist in all Azure containers that I have to sync with `azcopy sync`. After deleting the file, I run `azcopy sync` and when finished I check if the file I had deleted was restored.

I tried the same condition in my environment. I deleted the file is local environment and now I need to sync the file to storage account I used the below commands from local to azure portal.

```
 azcopy sync "C:\Users\xxxxx" "https://venkat123.blob.core.windows.net/container1<SAS-Token>" --recursive --delete-destination=true --mirror-mode
```

**Console:**

The above command synced with azure blob container from local environment and it get deleted in azure portal and logs can be seen with above command as below.

[image]

```
 azcopy sync "C:\Users\v-vsettu\xxxx" "https://venkat123.blob.core.windows.net/container1<SAS Token>" --recursive --delete-destination=true --mirror-mode
INFO: Any empty folders will not be processed, because source and/or destination doesn't have full folder support

Job d8d2e3c3-d583-0a4c-6841-da4c919004d0 has started
Log file is located at: C:\Users\v-vsettu\.azcopy\d8d2e3c3-d583-0a4c-6841-da4c919004d0.log

INFO: azcopy.exe: A newer version 10.17.0 is available to download

100.0 %, 1 Done, 0 Failed, 0 Pending, 1 Total, 2-sec Throughput (Mb/s): 0.0103

Job d8d2e3c3-d583-0a4c-6841-da4c919004d0 Summary
Files Scanned at Source: 1
Files Scanned at Destination: 1
Elapsed Time (Minutes): 0.067
Number of Copy Transfers for Files: 1
Number of Copy Transfers for Folder Properties: 0
Total Number Of Copy Transfers: 1
Number of Copy Transfers Completed: 1
Number of Copy Transfers Failed: 0
Number of Deletions at Destination: 0
Total Number of Bytes Transferred: 2575
Total Number of Bytes Enumerated: 2575
Final Job Status: Completed
```

**Portal:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[azcopy sync | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-sync)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I already have a working bash script with `azcopy`, but I think the way in which I am verifying if `azcopy` is doing its job is just inadequate. Using the presence of a single file to determine if the -whole sync process- completed successfully seems insufficient to me.

Perhaps the best way is to keep using my "single file verification strategy" -and- retrieve the `Final Job Status` from the log to verify that it appears as `Completed`?

If only `azcopy` could [behave as rsync](https://lxadm.com/rsync-exit-codes/), oh well...